# Can anyone help me how to bind a variable in a String?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, bind

Can someone help me in this problem.

```
function get_shareSearch($conn, $searchBy) { 
$id = "";
if(isset($_GET['share']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['share'];
        if($id == "%")
        {
            $id = "This is not going to work";
        }
    }
$statement = db_create_statement($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares WHERE company LIKE '%" . $id . "%' OR issue_date LIKE '%" . $id ."%' ORDER BY $searchBy ASC" );
db_bind($statement, ':id', $id);
$resultset = db_fetch_resultset($statement); 
return $resultset;
```

}

```
function db_bind($statement, $name, $value) {
return oci_bind_by_name($statement, $name, $value, 30);
```

}

**Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable**

can any one help me how to change variable id in the oracle statement so I could still have concatination plus to that to be able to bind the variable? Thank you.

```
  db_bind($statement, ':id', $id);
```

Comment: I am using that so when I am searching in my DataBase, if for example I have something named Cool so if I will search only for letter "o" it will display everyName that has this "o" in it, I make this like a concatination and not like a placeholder.

Comment: but I don't need the searchBy, I need id, the problem is about binding the id, searchBy works like that.

Comment: that's why I ask, I want to hold the operation of concatination and to use :id as well.

Comment: no, it's not, but what || means?

Comment: `if im doing like this `

 $statement = db_create_statement($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares WHERE company LIKE :id OR issue_date LIKE :id  OR rate LIKE :id   ORDER BY $searchBy ASC" );    
    db_bind($statement, ':id', $id);

It's working, but I loose the concatination ;(

Comment: @maraca it's working :D, I didnot replaced all occurence of $id in the query. Can you please post your answer as an answer? So I could mark it?

Comment: ok, i will. I had also troubles with binding a few times ;-) I'm sorry I downvoted you, first thought it is an already asked question and couldn't correct it then. If you do a minor edit like "can anyone help me how to bind a variable in a String?" then I am allowed to change my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind variables in a String they have to be concatenated (oracle notation):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares WHERE company LIKE '%' || :id || '%' OR issue_date LIKE '%' || :id || '%' ORDER BY $searchBy ASC
```

Comment: Thank you again, forgot that I can concatinate in oracle and not in php :D

Comment: Done. Thank you one more time.